# Serialize abstract class with Gson returns null

Tags: java, gson

I have a problem with goggles Gson library. Look at following code:

```
public abstract class Main { 
    public String foo = "foo";
    public List<String> bar = Arrays.asList( "foo", "bar" );


    @Override
    public String toString( ) {
        Gson gson = new Gson( );
        return gson.toJson( this );
    }

    public static void main( String[] args ) {
        Main main = new Main( ) {
        };
        System.out.println(main.toString( ));
    }
}
```

It prints `null`. But I would like it to print `{"foo":"foo","bar":["foo","bar"]}` which it does, when I remove the abstract identifier and the curly brackets after the creation of `Main( )`.

So how do I get the right output for an abstract class?

Comment: Are you trying to instantiate an abstract class?

Comment: @Atropo yes he did it using an anonymous class.

Comment: Sorry I didn't see the curly braces

Comment: title seems misleading, as this is not actually serializing abstract though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In case of abstract classes, you will need write your own adapter. See [this article](http://ovaraksin.blogspot.co.il/2011/05/json-with-gson-and-abstract-classes.html) on the subject.

Comment: Doesn't that only apply for deserialization, when you're trying to deserialize to an abstract type?  Gson introspects the class of the object you pass in, I don't think it should matter here.

Comment: Its in a sense symmetric : during serialization, some type info need to be keep also, but since toString only aware of the _static_ abstract type it can't work its magic (could be many derivation to this class). *Direct* call to gson.toJson( ) on the created instance of the anonymous class will work :)

Answer (score 2):

Looking at the code, I can see that Gson excludes anonymous inner classes.  The best explanation I have is because Gson's philosophy is to support symmetric serialization and deserialization, as explained in [this bug](https://code.google.com/p/google-gson/issues/detail?id=298):

> Don't use double brace initialization. It prevents [de]serialization and Gson is designed for symmetric serialization and [de]serialization.

It is impossible to deserialize an inner class without customization.  From the [users guide](https://sites.google.com/site/gson/gson-user-guide#TOC-Nested-Classes-including-Inner-Classes-):

> Gson can also deserialize static nested classes. However, Gson can not automatically deserialize the pure inner classes since their no-args constructor also need a reference to the containing Object which is not available at the time of deserialization.

Thus Gson prevents the serialization.  You could make the anonymous inner class a static nested class instead, and it would work.

Comment: I was using double brace initialization and thus it was not working. +1

Answer (score 0):

Sorry a bit late into this but for those who don't want to create nested class you can use this:

```
AbstractPayload payload = new AbstractPayload("field") {};
String result = gson.toJson(payload, AbstractPayload.class)
```

This worked for my case